# Recording two sound sources through two inputs at the same time with Tascam DR-1 Portable Digital?

Tags: tascam, portable, digital

Hello everyone here!

It's my second time to post question here :)

I have one simple question. I try to rent Tascam DR-1 Portable Digital, MKH 60, and MKH 416P for few days. I'm wondering if it's possible to select two inputs (MIC input 1, input 2) and record two sources at the same at separate tracks? I asked rental guy on this, and he said yes. But now I looked at the manual, but it seems like i can choose only one input at a time. Do i understand correctly?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it seems DR-1 has one stereo in and one mono in and you can choose one of them.
if you have already solved the phontom power problem and both mics have a minijack output adaptor you could use the DR-1 stereo in for the two mono sources.You need a third Y adaptor with 2 female mono in - one male stereo out.  You'll have a stereo track (dual mono) with one mic per channel and just have to split them.